# Unable to activate rspec-2.14.1, because rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1 conflicts with rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)

Tags: ruby, rspec, conflict, rbenv

I am new at ruby, please bear with me.

I am using rbenv, and I am trying to run tests on some practice ruby problems but I get this error:

> Unable to activate rspec-2.14.1, because rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1
>   conflicts with rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)

I updated my gems, but it still doesn't work. I don't know what's going on, what can I do to fix it?

If you need more information feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are using `bundler` to manage your gems run: `bundle exec rspec` instead of `rspec`

Comment: @bjhaid I can't use bundle, I don't have a gemfile since it's not a rails app :/ strictly ruby

Comment: create a `Gemfile` and let `bundler` manage your dependencies, alternatively uninstall `rspec` and its dependencies and re-install `rspec`, do note that you can use `Gemfile` outside rails

Comment: it doesn't have to be a rails or sinatra app or whatever. Get bundle from here http://bundler.io/ and then do what @bjhaid said. If you want send some links from the tutorial you follow.

Comment: bjhaid @appostolis it works! Thanks a lot for your help and for letting me know about the Gemfile versatility.

Comment: thanks @phoet will keep that link handy